# Program which compares two files and print the same line

Tags: awk

I have a problem. I want to create program, which print all lines which are in the first file and second file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {include[$0];next} $0 in include' eq3_dgdg_1.ndx eq3_dgdg_2.ndx | tee eq4_dgdg_2.ndx
```

eq3_dgdg_1.ndx input

```
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL1598
DGD2 SOL63
```

eq3_dgdg_2.ndx

```
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL1945
DGD2 SOL63
```

Output - **and here is an error** DGD1 SOL3605 - should be only once! Because I have in the first file only one line DGD1 SOL3605, not two, could you help me with that error?

```
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL63
```

Expected output

```
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL63
```

Comment: `sort file1 file2 | uniq -d >file3`

Comment: Can there be duplicate lines in the first file too or only in the second file? If there were 2 in each file would the line from file2 be output twice?

Comment: @EdMorton also in the first file

Comment: And would the output be 1 line or 2? While they will all produce the same output given your posted sample input, wich of the posted solutions will actually work for you depends on the answer to that question so you should really include that case in your sample input/output.

Comment: given sample is already sorted.. if duplicates can occur only in one of the files, `comm -12 f1 f2` will work

Comment: @EdMorton Only one line. I modified input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If duplicated lines in a file are allowed, you need a counter.
Give this a try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}a[$0]-->0' f1 f2
```

Let's have a test with your data:

```
kent$  head f*
==> f1 <==
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL1598
DGD2 SOL63

==> f2 <==
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL1945
DGD2 SOL63

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}a[$0]-->0' f1 f2
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL63
```

Comment: Thank you your script work the best with different repetitions in each file.

Comment: I have only one question what this "-->" do? I never use this in awk.

Comment: @Mark yes, `-->` looks odd. let's "format" it a bit, I think now you will understand it: `(a[$0]--)    >    0`

Answer (score 3):

Based on one possible interpretation of your question:

```
$ sort -u file2 | awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a' file1 -
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL63
```

or awk only:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $0 in a{print; delete a[$0]}' file1 file2
DGD1 SOL3605
DGD2 SOL1176
DGD2 SOL63
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next} ($0 in arr) && !arr2[$0]++' eq3_dgdg_1.ndx eq3_dgdg_2.ndx
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                             ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                          ##Checking condition FNR==NR for first file processing.
  arr[$0]                         ##Creating arr with index of current line.
  next                            ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($0 in arr) && !arr2[$0]++        ##Checking if current line present in arr AND current line coming first time in arr2 then print it.
' eq3_dgdg_1.ndx eq3_dgdg_2.ndx   ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```